# Missing functionalities for Microsoft Word's DATABASE Mail Merge field on MacOS

Tags: macos, ms-word, ms-office

After a migration from Windows to MacOS I'm facing issues with the DATABASE mail merge field.

I'm using an .xlsx file as a database, and in order to generate quotes or invoices, I have a bunch of fields set up (mainly of the type MERGEFIELD). Those are working as expected.

My one field of DATABASE type however is not working. Through trial and error I have determined that any "advanced" SQL functionality seems to be failing on Mac.

This works:

```
{ DATABASE \d "/Path/To/Local/xlsx/file.xlsx" \s "SELECT * FROM Clients" }
```

This doesn't yield the expected result (it returns all lines):

```
{ DATABASE \d "/Path/To/Local/xlsx/file.xlsx" \s "SELECT * FROM Clients LIMIT 1" }
```

A WHERE or a GROUP BY clause do not work either. These all work perfectly with Word running on Windows.

Any help is appreciated, my searches on Microsoft Office's help have not been helpful unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

Word's DATABASE field tries to execute the query you specify by sending it to the "query engine" that you specify in the Connection option in the DATABASE field.

In the Windows desktop version of Word, Word can send your query to an OLE DB provider or ODBC driver, e.g. SQL Server, Access, Excel, or even a text file. *Or* Word can use its own very simple dialect of SQL to execute a query.

If your data source is Access or Excel, you may not even be aware that the DATABASE field is using an OLE DB or ODBC connection, because Word tends to hide those details.

Mac Word does not recognise either OLE DB or ODBC connections, and can only execute Word's simple internal dialect of SQL.

(Much older versions of Mac Word used to be able to make ODBC connections)

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your answer. What isn't clear to me is whether :
1. there is no way to achieve what I'm trying to do on MacOS
2. I could achieve what I want to do by installing something? (some drivers? sqlServer?)

If you can clarify that I would gladly accept the answer